# fetch values from left to column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
13866           TRUE
18099           TRUE
16039           TRUE
16381   M       FALSE
16421   M   M   TRUE
16426   M       FALSE
16387   M   M   TRUE
16431   M       FALSE
16432   M       FALSE
16385   M   M   TRUE
16423   M       FALSE
16430   M       FALSE
16380   M   O   FALSE
```

The column A contains value and Column C contains either True or False based on exact formula used in column C. Basically, I need to fetch values from column A only if value in column C is "FALSE" in another tab of excel sheet.

Please help.

Comment: `If` condition perhaps?

Comment: I tried If. It's not working. I tried to use Index and Match combination. But I am getting #N/A instead of value. Please help me out on this.

Comment: Check my answer .. and BTW there are 2 columns for M and O ... so true false column would be D.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me though. I used `IF` and it fetched the required values (see screenshots). Are you sure you don't have extra spaces in col D?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a Lot. It works. Can you please provide me VBA, Then it would be more helpful as data is quite large.

Comment: Technically, you just have to insert the formula in first cell and then you can drag and copy the formula for the entire range.